# CXF webservices (SOAP/JMS) using RabbitMQ

Tags: web-services, jms, cxf, rabbitmq, spring-jms

I have a CXF webservice which is supporting SOAP over JMS, where I have used ActiveMQ as message broker system. The soap messages are sent to the request queue and soap responses are sent back to reply queue. Now I am planning to replace RabbitMQ with ActiveMQ. But the issue I am facing is that RabbitMQ doesn't implement JMS APIs. Can we use RabbitMQ for SOAP/JMS webservices?

Note: I am using `org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConfigFeature` as `jaxws:features` in the spring config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state, RabbitMQ does not support JMS so the simple answer is no, you can't do SOAP over JMS with RabbitMQ.

However, Pivotal has a [(commercial) JMS library connector implementation for RabbitMQ](http://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal/products/messaging-with-jms-and-rabbitmq) that should make it possible.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But as you told its commercial, that means it will be not opensource .. right ?

Comment: Correct; open source RabbitMQ does NOT support JMS natively. JMS is an API whereas AMQP is a protocol.

Comment: Can we use SOAP over AMQP then for sending SOAP messages to RabbitMQ. Is it possible ? I am using Apache CXF webservices to build my webservices.

Comment: It's certainly __possible__ but I don't know if CXF supports it out of the box so you might have to provide some glue code.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your valuable answers. I will do some R&D on SOAP over AMQP using spring integration. Lets see.